# JSON params POST not recognize with AFNetworking

Tags: json, ios6, afnetworking

[Solved]
I'm trying to edit AFHTTPClient.m to make it work with POST Method in

```
-(NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                  path:(NSString *)path
                            parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

like this :

```
if ([method isEqualToString:@"GET"] ||[method isEqualToString:@"POST"] || [method isEqualToString:@"HEAD"] || [method isEqualToString:@"DELETE"])
```

I have problem with POST method with params userDevice ,I have function subclass from AFHTTPClient like this

EDIT:

I used different method like this but same result

```
-(void)loginWithEmail:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)passwords
{

NSString *baseurl = @"http://localhost.com:9000/";

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseurl]];

[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:email password:passwords];
```

and then this is my params :

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      model, @"deviceModel",
                      systemVersion, @"deviceVersion",
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:0], @"productionMode",
                      appVersion, @"appVersion",
                      deviceType,@"deviceType", nil];

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary* jsonObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:data, @"userDevice", nil];

NSData *jsonLogin =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonLoginString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonLogin encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON LOGIN OUTPUT :%@", jsonLoginString);

[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
```

I request using this code :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:@"/ios/login"
                                                  parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonLoginString,@"userDevice", nil]
                                ];    
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = nil;

operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
             JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
             success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                 NSLog(@"Response : %@", request);
                 NSLog(@"JSON: %@",JSON);

             }
             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error , id JSON ){

                 NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
             }];

[operation start];
```

this is the example json that I wanted :

```
"userDevice" : {
    "appVersion" : "1.0",
    "deviceModel" : "iPhone Simulator",
    "productionMode" : false,
    "deviceType" : "iPhone Simulator",
    "deviceVersion" : "6.1"
}
```

am I missing something?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @LithuT.V the error : userDevice wrong from my server, and when I nslog jsonObject the result has wrong format,
userDevice ={
        appVersion = "1.0";
        deviceModel = "iPhone Simulator";
        deviceType = "iPhone Simulator";
        deviceVersion = "6.1";
        productionMode = 0;
    };
 they used "=" not ":" as my example json at above any idea ?